# How to upgrade from Fedora 21 to higher stable version with the highest convenience and safety?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, upgrade

I am still working on a Fedora 21 Linux. I know Fedora 22, 23 and 24 already are around.I am not sure how to upgrade my Linux to a stable version of fedora with the highest conveniece as well as safety. Could anyone help me with the upgrade for a non-advanced user as a result of which I will be using all the packages I have in Fedora 21 but under a higher version? Is it true to say that there should be a way according to which I don't have to reinstall my repository packages (and maybe even my data files and scripts)?

Here is the result of running `uname -a`

> Linux localhost.localdomain 4.1.13-100.fc21.i686+PAEdebug #1 SMP Tue
>   Nov 10 13:15:09 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

***First***, let me warn you that upgrading any OS in place has the potential to fail and then cause problems resulting from that failure.

Having said that, [Fedora 24 is still not yet released](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/24/Schedule), so the latest official release of Fedora is Fedora 23.  Instructions for that upgrade can be found at [the Fedora Project Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading).  There are multiple methods for performing the upgrade:  [DNF](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade), [yum](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_package_manager), and [FedUp](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/upgrading-from-fedora-20-to-fedora-23/) are the most common.  Upgrading via FedUp is [now considered obsolete](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp), as is upgrading via yum.  The officially recommended method is currently using DNF, which has been installed on Fedora since Fedora 18, so you should already have this on your system.

Instead of blindly following the commands I provide below, I highly recommend that you read over the [DNF system upgrade notes](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade) from the Fedora Project Wiki.

The quick 'n' dirty is:

1. Backup your stuff
2. Open a terminal
3. Run the standard DNF update
4. Install the DNF system upgrade plugin
5. Download the system upgrade packages
6. Run the upgrade and reboot

The terminal commands necessary to run steps 3-6 are:

```
$ sudo dnf update --refresh
$ sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade
$ sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=23
$ sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

You *may* wish to first upgrade to Fedora 22 and *then* upgrade to Fedora 23 rather than jumping straight to Fedora 23, but either process *should* work.

Comment: I just noticed that in order to install dnf on my system from Aper repository, it says that 52 packages will be removed. Is this normal and safe?

Comment: I don't have a Fedora system available to test this, but assuming you ran "[yum install dnf](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Dnf#Installation)", then I'd hazard a guess that that's normal behavior.